# File lock on webserver The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext

I am trying to create/overwrite a pdf that was just generated on a folder on my webserver. If I run the code below locally in development it seems to work fine. But if I run it over the web after publishing it I get the message that The process cannot access the file  because it is being used by another process. even though no one has it open. I have tried to Dispose(), Close() and Flush() but no luck. Is there something else I can try? TIA

```
Dim Doc1 As New Document
    Dim path As String = "\\server\PDFs\"

    Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", random)
    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))

    Doc1.Open()
    Dim test As String
    test = Session("PDF")
    Dim PDFHeader As String
    PDFHeader = Session("Header")
    Dim imagepath As String = Server.MapPath(".") & "/images/Header.png"
    Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath)
    image.ScalePercent(70.0F)
    Dim line1 As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(0.0F, 100.0F, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1)

    Doc1.Add(image)
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(PDFHeader))
    Doc1.Add(New Chunk(line1))
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))
    Doc1.Close()
    Doc1.Dispose()

    pdfWrite.Dispose()
    pdfWrite.Flush()
    pdfWrite.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem before with the same error and it was actually a permissions problem.  I don't know how the .pdf is originally getting created there, but in my case, if I copied a file directly to the location on the remote server from my local PC, I got the error, but if I copied it somewhere else, then Remoted in to the server and moved it to that location, it changed the permissions and I could access the file.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Whats funny is it will work after a few hours. Somehow it releases the lock or something on it after a little time